# Initalizing a cpp class with new

Tags: c++, class, new-operator

I have created a Vector3 class:

```
 class Vector3{

   public:
   float x, y, z;
};
```

I can do this:

```
Vector3 v;
v.x = 0.0f;
v.y = 0.0f;
v.z = 0.0f
```

I want to initialize it like this:

```
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: why do you want that? Why not `auto v = Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)` ?

Comment: `new` returns a *pointer*. You can only use `new` like this: `Vector3* v = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`, but you should *really* avoid manual memory management.

Comment: What's the problem, or error you got?

Comment: `new Vector3{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};` or need a constructor.

Comment: When I set it as a pointer like `Vector3 *v = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`, it says `no suitable constructor exists to convert from "float" to "Vector3"`

Comment: Do you really want to use `new`? C++ is quite different from Java and C#.

Comment: @LouisGo I want to use new, but i can live with something else

Comment: what makes us wonder is **why** do you want to use `new`? `new` is not the idomatic way to create objects in C++. It is in other languages, which often causes major confusion

Comment: @idclev463035818 I want to manually allocate memory, but it is not necessary for now.

Comment: " I want to manually allocate memory" why? Lots of effort has been put into C++ in past years so that you never need to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are asking how to write a constructor that initializes the members:

```
class Vector3{
    public:
    float x, y, z;
    Vector3(float a,float b, float c) : x(a),y(b),z(c) {}
    Vector3() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), z(0.0f) {}
};
```

Now you can write

```
Vector3 v(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3 v2;
```

Do not use `new` to create objects. If you really need a dynamically allocated object, then use a smart pointer.

Comment: tried this `Vector3 v = Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` , got `no instance of constructor "Vector3::Vector3" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (float, float, float)`

Comment: @JamesB.Reese fixed the example